# awk not printing correct value for 1 condition that uses multiple criteria

Tags: awk

Thanks to @Jose Ricardo Bustos M. whos help led to the below using `file1` and `file2`:

However, I can not seem to capture `BRCA2` from `file1` with `BRCA 1, BRCA2` from `file2` (line 2 skipping the header). I am not sure if this is because `BCRA2` is the second instance after the `,` or if problem that `$7`is `full gene sequence and full deletion/duplication analysis`, that is `full gene sequence` is a partial match to the full line in `$7`?  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
BRCA2
BCR
SCN1A
fbn1
```

**file2**

```
Tier    explanation .   List code   gene    gene name   methodology disease
Tier 1  .   .   811 DMD dystrophin  deletion analysis and duplication analysis, if performed Publication Date: January 1, 2014  Duchenne/Becker muscular dystrophy
Tier 1  .   Jan-16  81  BRCA 1, BRCA2   breast cancer 1 and 2   full gene sequence and full deletion/duplication analysis   hereditary breast and ovarian cancer
Tier 1  .   Jan-16  70  ABL1    ABL1    gene analysis variants in the kinse domane  acquired imatinib tyrosine kinase inhibitor
Tier 1  .   .   806 BCR/ABL 1   t(9;22) major breakpoint, qualitative or quantitative   chronic myelogenous leukemia CML
Tier 1  .   Jan-16  85  FBN1    Fibrillin   full gene sequencing    heart disease
Tier 1  .   Jan-16  95  FBN1    fibrillin   del/dup heart disease
```

**awk**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}  # define fs and output
{$0=toupper($0)}  # convert all `file1` to uppercase
{$5=toupper($5)} # convert '$5' in `file2` to uppercase
{$7=toupper($7)} # convert '$7' in `file2` to uppercase
FNR==NR{ # process each field in line of `file1`
if(NR>1 && ($7 ~ /FULL GENE SEQUENC/)) {  # skip header and check for full gene sequenc or full gene sequencing, using `regexp`
      gsub(" ","",$5)       #removing white space
      n=split($5,v,"/")
      d[v[1]] = $4          #from split, first element as key
  }
  next
}{print $1, ($1 in d?d[$1]:279)}' file2 file1 # print name then default if no match

BRCA2    279
BCR    279
SCN1A    279
FBN1    85
```

desired output

```
BRCA2    81  --- match in line 2 of $5 in file 2, BRCA 1, BRCA2 and $7 has full gene sequence
BCR    279
SCN1A    279
FBN1    85
```

Comment: The partial match should be fine for `$7 ~ /.../`, but for `$1 in d` it has to be an exact match.

Comment: Debug your code. Add printing of intermediate variables, and check what does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the below part in the code,

```
gsub(" ","",$5)
n=split($5,v,"/")
d[v[1]] = $4
```

AFAIK, it is handling good for the case, `BCR/ABL 1` properly, but when you use it for `BRCA 1, BRCA2` it does *NOT* produce results as you expect it to be. Removing white-spaces on `BRCA 1, BRCA2` would be `BRCA1,BRCA2` and splitting by `/` would produce the same string `BRCA1,BRCA2` itself, as the de-limiter is wrong.

So you need the split string again by `,` and hash-it. Something like,

```
n=split($5,v,",")
for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
  d[v[i]] = $4
}
```

So that now `d` is hashed with `d[BRCA1]` and `d[BRCA2]`. Use the above along with your existing code.

Or) remove the code

```
gsub(" ","",$5)
n=split($5,v,"/")
d[v[1]] = $4
```

altogether and do,

```
gsub(" ","",$5)
n=split($5,v,"\\||,") 
for (i=1; i <= n; i++) {
  d[v[i]] = $4
}
```

which means split `$5` on either `|` or `,` and loop over its contents and hash it to the array `d`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and explanations, I really appreciate them :).